# how to put an image view on top of a surfaceview android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have Surface view which i have set the setZOrderOnTop(true);
When i have recorded a video on this view, set display of the media player to this view and then I set the visibility of images over it to true I can see the images over this surface view.

Now when I set the mediaplayer.start() the video plays but the images over this surface view disappear, and they aren't even visible even after I explicitly set surfaceview setZOrderOnTop(false); and the visibility of the images to Visible in onCompletion of the media player. But the imageviews onclick is enabled

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The View UI is on one layer, the SurfaceView Surface is on a different layer.  You can put the SurfaceView Surface in front of or behind the View elements, but you can't put it between Views, and you can't change the position once the Surface has been created:

> Note that this must be set before the surface view's containing window is attached to the window manager.

You can solve it on API 14+ by sending your video to a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) instead.  TextureViews are less efficient, but can be manipulated in the layout like any other View.

Comment: Yeah but why is that when only I start the media player the surface view comes in front and hides the image views. Please help.

Comment: How can I change the Z order ( setZOrderOnTop(true); to setZOrderOnTop(false);)??? Please Help me. if this is not possible please give me a solution to how I can remove the surface view and add the surface view to the layout.